# TYPO3 9 LTS type casting error on mysql time field for TCA type input / dbType time saving empty field

Tags: mysql, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-tca

I'm trying to have a time input in TYPO3 9 LTS working together with MySQL 5.7.24.

In the `ext_tables.sql` the field gets defined like this:

`some_field time default NULL`

In the TCA the field gets defined like this:

```
  'some_field' => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'Some field',
    'config' => [
      'type' => 'input',
      'dbType' => 'time',
      'eval' => 'time',
    ],
  ],
```

When saving the record in the backend without a time input (which should be possible) I'm getting the error:

`These fields of record 1 in table "some_table" have not been saved correctly: some_field! The values might have changed due to type casting of the database.`

When looking at the database record the `some_field` field gets the value `00:00:00` (although the db default is `NULL`).

When selecting a time the record can be saved and opened without error.

Is this a bug in TYPO3 or how could I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug can be solved by having the following `eval`:

```
'eval' => 'time,null',
```

Comment: The documentation is now updated with the solution mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

That means you have given the wrong type for the value on your ext_tables.sql. Additionally, TYPO3 v9 has `renderTypes`.
Try something like that:

**ext_tables.sql**

```
begin int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
```

**TCA**

```
'begin' => [
   'exclude' => true,
   'label' => 'LLL:EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_yourext_domain_model_modelname.begin',
   'config' => [
        'type' => 'input',
        'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
         'size' => 10,
         'eval' => 'datetime',
         'default' => time()
     ],
],
```

**Additional information!**

If you want to display the time in FrontEnd you could use something like that

```
<f:format.date>{dateObject.begin}</f:format.date>
```

If you want to modify how it looks, you can use the **format** attribute as well:

```
<f:format.date format="%d. %B %Y">{dateObject.begin}</f:format.date>
```

More about that here: [TYPO3 Date format](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Format/Date.html)

Comment: I want to use the "time" type and TYPO3 does support it since 9 LTS as you can see here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input.html#dbtype - Bug report for TYPO3 right here -> https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88712

Comment: then read carefully what the documentation says http://prntscr.com/od17gc

Comment: I don't know what you try to explain to me. The property is set. The docs talk about "When this property is *not* set".

Comment: what if you add the int on the eval? to look like this: 'eval' => 'time, int',

Comment: Actually, time type for mysql is fine – you need to add null to eval:
`'eval' => 'time,null'`
in ext_tables.sql:
`some_field time default NULL`
is fine also.